# Dynamic Pivoting in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Hi I want to apply dynamic pivoting on table with structure as

```
ID  Type    Amount
--- ------  ------
1   AB      50
2   PQR     100
3   AB      60
4   PQR     120
```

I want result in below format:

[image]

In my table, every month Type column's values changing. So I want dynamically pivot table values to get desired result. I was tried by pivoting as per syntax , but whenever I tried to place sub-query in IN operator of pivot, it has given an error. I am using Oracle 10 g. 
Can anyone please assist me in this issue. Thanks.

```
Select * from(
              Select ID , Type, Value 
                from mytable)x
               pivot(sum(Value) for Type IN (Select distinct Type from myTable))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have dynamic results, you may prefer using `xml` option of `pivoting`

```
with t(ID, Type, Amount) as
(
 select 1,'AB',50 from dual union all
 select 2,'PQR',100 from dual union all
 select 3,'AB',60 from dual union all
 select 4,'PQR',120 from dual
)
select * 
  from(
       select ID , Type, Amount 
         from t )
    pivot xml( 
               sum(Amount) as sum_amount for (type) 
                 in (Select distinct Type from t)
              );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/AOAC37213)